# can't cast int to char with Java

Tags: java, casting

I was given an assignment to generate a random number between 1 to 26 then convert that number to a letter from 'a' to 'z'.
the random generating part looks fine but when I try to cast the number to char, I would just get an empty square-like box!
why is that?

```
    import java.util.Random;
    public class NumbersToLetters 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Random n;
            int num;
            n=new Random();
    //generating a random number from 1 to 26
            num=Math.abs(((n.nextInt())%26)+1); 
    //cast from int to char
            char myChar = (char) num; 
            System.out.println ("Number - " + num); 
            System.out.println ("Char - " + myChar);

   //I'm sure that my answer is right but no matter what I do,
   //it won't output a letter, all I get is a square-like box..
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try doing 'char myChar = (char) (num + 97)'. Why? http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Comment: Note that netbeans is just an IDE, this is all just Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're generating a number between 1 and 27 (inclusive). If you look at [what those characters correspond to](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/ascii.html), you'll see that none of them are actually printable.

You should do your calculation as `+ 'a'` instead of `+ 1`

```
n.nextInt(26) + 'a';
```

This will give you the correct offset (which happens to be 97) to find the lower case letters.

Answer (score 2):

The character `'a'` is not encoded as `1`, but as `97`. You need to add `'a'` to a value between 0 and 25 (inclusive) to get the expected result:

```
num = 'a'+n.nextInt(26);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java guru like others on here, but it might have something to do with not being encoded correctly? Look up UTF-8 encoding and just research type casting